# Why react render accepts a block and return doesn't?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React JS, and facing a problem with JSX. I have a component :

The below code works fine:

```
import React from "react";

function Hello() {
  return(<h1> Hello ! </h1>);
}

export default Hello;
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
import React from "react";

function Hello() {
  return(){
  <h1> Hello ! </h1>
  };
}

export default Hello;
```

As I am trying to use a block in return, Why does render(){} accepts a block and return does not?

Comment: Because `render` is a _method_ (and goes in a _class_ definition, not a _function_ definition), and `return` is a _statement_.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a functional-based component you can't define a render function inside this works only on class-based components

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
  }
}
```